# error in style.xml file in android

Tags: android, styles

Error:(4, 5) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'colorPrimary' with value '@color/colorPrimary').

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Holmes\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

I am working on an application of login and registration page .everything was fine suddenly i experience this error as mentioned above and an error in my .java file saying cannot resolve symbol R.I have cleaned my project and synced again still this error is not going please help me .

Comment: Have you tried changing that value to something else?

Comment: how to change this value?

Comment: Is this a programming error or something else ?

Comment: The code you have there is expecting a value for colorPrimary.  And it looks like that value itself, is defined elsewhere.  Just hardcode it to some Hex value or something.